# Problem Loading raster from WMS server

Tags: raster, wms, pyqgis-3

What am I doing wrong? I am not able to receive the raster layer. However, when I am opening the url from the browser I am able to receive the image.

```
from qgis.core import *


url='url=http://geodata.gov.gr/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&bbox=448789,4177572,501682,4222482&crs=EPSG:2100&width=431&height=365&layers=geodata.gov.gr:18fe8202-e9de-4b83-a6ac-d4978b690b46&styles&format=image/png&dpi=96&map_resolution=96&format_options=dpi:96'
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(url, 'test', 'wms')


print(rlayer.isValid())
# Gives True
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

But the layer doesn't load

[image: error loading layer]

The warning in the logs is:

> 2020-03-11T16:15:41     WARNING    Map request failed [error: Error transferring http://geodata.gov.gr:80/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=448789,4177572,501682,4222482&CRS=EPSG:2100&WIDTH=357&HEIGHT=303&LAYERS=geodata.gov.gr:18fe8202-e9de-4b83-a6ac-d4978b690b46&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE - server replied: Service Unavailable url: http://geodata.gov.gr:80/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=448789,4177572,501682,4222482&CRS=EPSG:2100&WIDTH=357&HEIGHT=303&LAYERS=geodata.gov.gr:18fe8202-e9de-4b83-a6ac-d4978b690b46&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE]

But the service request in a browser works.

Using the QGIS Network Logger plugin, I can see that after `rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(url, 'test', 'wms')` A GetCapabilities request is sent:

```
http://geodata.gov.gr/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 QGIS/31002'  --compressed
```

and a successful response is received.

I guess that the True response from `print(rlayer.isValid())`
is a reflection of the successful GetCapabilities request.

Comment: what is the error message? what is returned?

Comment: I edited the url string. I had to put the fields in lower case. However, when I am trying to add the layer, I get error transferring. Try it your self just copy/paste

Comment: Just on the WMS request itself `service=wms&` is not correct the specification says it must be `service=WMS&`

Comment: @nmtoken its not working even with this. feel free to copy/paste it and test it.

Comment: @nmtoken if you try to load the layer in the project, it fails.

Comment: Agree, if I use, `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)`   I get a layer label called test but a message saying Error transferring.. so possibly it's a bug. However, if I use the QGIS Network logger to look at the requests, it appears that it's the server that's refusing the request (I see HTTP 500 and 403 responses.

Comment: @nmtoken how is this possible since the isValid function returns True.. Also how is this possible since the very same url works in the browser?

Comment: As I said could be a bug, so best raise on QGIS issues